# How to test dynamic text on webpage that stays on only for 2-3 seconds, using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dynamic, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnNpJ.png)Dynamic Text like Sign in Successful/Sign is Failed

I tried getting text on the div at the time this message will be disaplyed, but its giving blank output.

```
<div class="Toaster-style__toaster___1WB4l">
<div></div> --> **this div will have dynamic text**
</div>
```

Comment: Can you try this thread, https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23367/how-to-verify-a-success-message-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @Snehal Your code trials please